# Making automated ID in VBA

Tags: vba, variables, object

I am new in and is trying to give an automated ID in which i used the following code:

```
y = 0
If txtdsgnation = "Plumbing" Then
x = "P"
Do Until Cells(i, 3) = ""        
    If Cells(i, 3) = "Plumbing" Then
    y = y + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End If
If txtdsgnation = "Electricity" Then
x = "E"
Do Until Cells(i, 3) = ""

    If Cells(i, 3) = "Electricity" Then
    y = y + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End If
If txtdsgnation = "Fittings" Then
x = "F"
Do Until Cells(i, 3) = ""

    If Cells(i, 3) = "Fittings" Then
    y = y + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End If
If txtdsgnation = "Lift maintenance" Then
x = "L"
Do Until Cells(i, 3) = ""

    If Cells(i, 3) = "Lift maintenance" Then
    y = y + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End If

z = 100 + y

txtID = x + "-" + z
```

The thing i am trying to do is that if i add a new employee, for example a plumber and I already have 2 plumbers txtID will automatically become "P-102"
Thanks in advance

Comment: should be: txtID = x + "-" + CStr(z)

Answer (score 0):

In the loop, the y is always getting initialized with 0. So, y has no chance to become more than 1. Please try to put the y out of the loop.

Comment: Opps sorry... but that is not the problem is that these two line donot work...
z = 100 + y
 and
 txtID = x + "-" + z